# Laravel: Two foreign keys to from Ticket Model to two instances of User Model

Tags: laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, relational-database

I'm making a small ticket booking service. My goal is to link the ticket model to two User instances: 1. The manager who created the ticket 2. The user who owns the ticket.

I have two models:

**User**

table

```
id
name
email
manager
```

model

```
public function myticket() {
return $this->hasMany(App::Ticket);
} //this is for the ticket owner

public function createdticket() {
return $this->hasMany(App::Ticket);
} //this is for the manager who created the ticket
```

**Ticket**

table

```
id
ticketcode

$table->integer(user_id)->unsigned(); //the user who owns the ticket
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');

$table->integer(manager_id)->unsigned(); //the manager who created 
$table->foreign('manager_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

model

```
public function user() {
return $this->belongsTo(App::User);
} //this is for the ticket owner

public function createdby() {
return $this->belongsTo(App::User);
} //this is for the manager who created the ticket
```

How can I adjust my code to make this eloquent compliant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing is adding exact columns into your relations.

In `User` model it should be:

```
public function myticket() 
{
    return $this->hasMany(App::Ticket, 'user_id');
} //this is for the ticket owner

public function createdticket() 
{
    return $this->hasMany(App::Ticket, 'manager_id');
} //this is for the manager who created the ticket
```

And for `Ticket` model it should be:

```
public function user() 
{
   return $this->belongsTo(App::User, 'user_id');
} //this is for the ticket owner

public function createdBy() 
{
   return $this->belongsTo(App::User,'manager_id');
} //this is for the manager who created the ticket
```

You can ignore `user_id` in those relationships because it's by default, but in case you have relations with other names and multiple users for readability it's better to include them